# How do you get the toy hammer?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I don't know where to get the toy hammer in Animal Crossing New Leaf. Someone said in a gift shop but I don't know which one. The island or the 2nd floor museum gift shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Toy Hammer](https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Toy_hammer) will rarely appear in the shop on Tortimer Island, and can be purchased for 10 medals.